# A good way to check a character for 平仄格律?

Tags: resources, poetry

I already have some basic knowledge of this in general, from mandarin and cantonese vocab.  However, I am dipping my toes into poetry and thought an actual resource of rhyming for characters would be good.

In my mind I am picturing a regular 詞典 or 字典， but with a simple marker of which of the five poetic tones it was.

I am open to a different style resource as well, as long as it is a website I can use on a phone that would be ideal.

Does not need to have any english entries etc.

Comment: You may be interested in this article about 平仄格律. https://www.bing.com/search?q=%E5%B9%B3%E4%BB%84%E6%A0%BC%E5%BE%8B&FORM=SSQUIC&PC=U531&lightschemeovr=1

Comment: @r13 I am interested, this is very interesting for the overal structures.  my main question was for things like 出 which in modern mandarin would look like 平 but I know from cantonese is classically 仄.  I imagine there are such changes to things in ways I wouldn't recognize so easily.

Comment: 懂粵語的入應能提供其壓韻的技巧和規則,我拭目以待 :)

Comment: This is a must-read for 粵語聲調和字典中的標記. https://www.facebook.com/CantoneseMuseum/posts/1694221787254693/

Comment: @r13 this is very helpful! now I just need to know if this is (almost) always true, or if there are many exceptions like where something that is currently 平 used to not be etc :)

Comment: You got me. Hope someone comes to help quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

> five poetic tones it was

isn’t it four (平上去入) only?

try these:

[漢語多功能字庫](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/)

i used this one to check the tone of syllable in cantonese

[宋本広韻](https://kanji-database.sourceforge.net/dict/sbgy/index.html)

this one is an “online” version of 廣韻

[小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)

i used this one to check the tone in various rhymes books

have fun :)

Comment: it is five, for example  cantonese still has the 入 tones no longer in mandarin, which is a major reason classical works rhyme better in cantonese than mandarin (although not perfect).  neither cantonese nor mandarin match perfectly, what with four and six tones each a bit different from those in classical poetry.

Comment: I didn't see what I was hoping for at a glance on these, although they seem to perform subpar on a phone vs a computer unfortunately. I will keep looking to see if I find a part of them that works for me, if the rhyme dictionary is searchable and I can get it to work somehow that may do it.